# How to use batching in Fluent NHibernate + SQLite

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, batch-processing

Anyone tried to enable batching support using Fluent NHibernate in pair with SQLite? I tried

```
Fluently.Configure()
.Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
.UsingFile(CreateOrGetDataFile()).AdoNetBatchSize(128))
.Mappings( 
m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("Sauron.Core"))
.Conventions.Add(PrimaryKey.Name.Is(p => "Id"), ForeignKey.EndsWith("Id")))
.BuildSessionFactory();
```

but didn't work.

also I tried setting batch size on ISession and IStatelessSession but I got exception saying that batching is disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batching is not yet supported for SQLite. It's only implemented for SQLServer and Oracle.

You don't necessarily have to wait for that to happen, though. You can implement `IBatcherFactory` and `IBatcher`.

Answer (score 0):

What id generation strategy are you using? Server-generated ones (identity, sequences) don't allow batching.

Comment: I'm using assigned strategy... In other words, I'm assigning ids by hand